# java regex : Split function

Tags: java, regex

What this regex will do :

`String[] lines = inputString.split("[\r]?\n");`

Comment: It should have been written as `\r?\n`. The brackets are meaningless.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 1):

It will get an array and in each rows you will have a line even if it's a Linux or Windows enconding